# Появление верхней границы монтажной области элемента svg при масштабировании

Tags: svg

Во всех браузерах при масштабировании страницы на iPhone 11, где расположено svg-изображение, появляется верхняя граница монтажной области элементов, из которых состоит изображение. Причем, если увеличишь сильнее, то она пропадает, чуть уменьшишь, появится в другом месте. На десктопных браузерах всё отображается корректно. Также отмечу, что на iPhone 7 - тоже всё отображается корректно во всех браузерах.

Ниже пример со стороннего сайта. У меня есть свои svg-изображения, которые тоже проявляют верхнюю границу монтажной области на iPhone 11. Пытался различные атрибуты добавлять в svg и свойства к контейнеру, но вообще ничего не помогло.

Подскажите, почему такое поведение и как можно решить эту проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     width="640.000000pt" height="1280.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 640.000000 1280.000000" 
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"> 
    <metadata> 
    Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017 
    </metadata> 
    <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" 
    fill="#000000" stroke="none"> 
    <path d="M3110 12794 c-14 -2 -63 -9 -110 -15 -96 -12 -373 -59 -378 -64 -2 
    -1 4 -98 13 -215 9 -116 14 -214 11 -217 -13 -14 -34 9 -39 44 -8 50 -30 69 
    -87 78 -40 6 -50 3 -86 -23 -98 -71 -98 -193 0 -264 36 -26 46 -29 86 -23 55 
    8 78 27 86 71 5 27 11 34 30 34 18 0 24 -5 24 -23 0 -30 18 -280 25 -333 4 
    -35 1 -43 -14 -47 -25 -6 -41 11 -41 44 0 45 -30 71 -86 76 -63 6 -110 -23 
    -142 -89 -34 -67 -24 -118 33 -175 39 -39 47 -43 93 -43 60 0 91 21 101 70 5 
    28 12 36 34 38 33 4 33 4 47 -198 14 -209 14 -210 -9 -210 -15 0 -20 10 -25 
    45 -9 55 -34 75 -95 75 -83 0 -151 -71 -151 -157 0 -73 75 -153 143 -153 63 0 
    85 14 98 65 10 38 15 45 35 45 13 0 24 -6 24 -12 0 -7 5 -65 10 -129 l11 -116 
    89 -169 c56 -108 84 -170 76 -172 -9 -2 -12 -68 -12 -295 1 -294 -3 -550 -29 
    -1932 -8 -412 -17 -941 -21 -1175 -3 -234 -8 -441 -9 -460 -2 -19 -3 -94 -4 
    -167 l-1 -132 -42 -5 c-24 -3 -88 -10 -143 -16 -406 -46 -749 -152 -986 -305 
    -41 -26 -113 -86 -160 -134 -171 -171 -239 -346 -239 -609 1 -292 60 -481 230 
    -737 92 -138 142 -238 172 -340 19 -68 23 -104 23 -240 0 -155 -1 -163 -33 
    -255 -51 -145 -137 -296 -368 -641 -253 -378 -344 -526 -434 -710 -149 -306 
    -202 -554 -180 -846 12 -156 28 -250 64 -373 179 -613 719 -1017 1575 -1180 
    561 -106 1201 -106 1762 0 856 163 1396 567 1575 1180 36 123 52 217 64 373 
    22 292 -31 540 -180 846 -90 184 -181 332 -434 710 -232 347 -318 497 -367 
    641 -28 83 -33 111 -37 225 -7 236 32 358 195 614 140 219 188 340 218 546 19 
    127 19 311 0 397 -32 154 -97 269 -220 394 -102 102 -176 154 -320 224 -224 
    108 -486 177 -830 219 l-140 17 -6 209 c-4 116 -9 392 -13 615 -7 412 -16 914 
    -37 2000 -7 333 -13 770 -13 972 -1 265 -4 368 -12 370 -7 2 27 76 77 171 l89 
    168 10 112 c5 62 10 120 10 130 0 11 8 17 24 17 20 0 25 -7 35 -45 9 -34 18 
    -48 37 -55 46 -18 95 -12 131 16 73 55 91 129 53 205 -27 52 -72 79 -132 79 
    -59 0 -85 -22 -94 -80 -5 -30 -11 -40 -25 -40 -23 0 -23 0 -9 199 15 211 16 
    213 48 209 21 -2 28 -10 33 -38 10 -48 41 -70 100 -70 42 0 55 5 88 36 65 58 
    76 128 31 202 -57 93 -192 98 -215 7 -13 -53 -21 -64 -44 -58 -15 4 -19 12 
    -15 36 5 42 24 306 24 340 0 22 5 27 25 27 20 0 25 -6 31 -34 8 -45 29 -63 84 
    -71 40 -6 50 -3 86 23 98 71 98 193 0 264 -36 26 -46 29 -86 23 -57 -9 -77 
    -26 -85 -77 -6 -35 -27 -59 -41 -45 -3 2 2 94 10 203 9 110 16 206 16 215 0 
    18 -57 31 -312 70 -128 19 -346 32 -398 23z"/> 
    </g> 
  </svg>
```

Comment: Надо видить svg, где код?

Comment: Добавил код изображения

Comment: посмотрел я на 11 айфоне  и на макбуке - не увидел этой проблемы... не могу помочь